# Hide all pages (not posts) that Editor is not author of from Editors Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I have below code that works and hides (from non authors) all pages AND posts from being displayed when standard WordPress "Editor" role logs in and tries to view them in dashboard. This way Editors can only see posts/pages they are author of.

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ){ //is not admin
    global $user_level;
    if($query->is_admin) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author',  $user_ID);
        unset($user_ID);
    }
    unset($user_level);
    return $query;  
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

I've been trying to modify this code to hide only pages but not posts - without success.

Below change in code causes both all posts and pages to be visible to Editor

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) && $query->is_page ){ //is not admin is page
```

what i do wrong?

PS: I'm aware that its now what standard editor role is for - this is just an example for any custom role.

Edit:
I've found a solution but its not pretty:

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'update_core' ) && $_GET['post_type']=="page"){
```

If someone knows better way I'd appreciate it. Notice i don't need it to be super secure.